# Standard price book always showing as Default price book in Opportunity Products

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

Whenever we are trying to add Opportunity Products on the Opportunity, 'Standard price book' is always showing as default price book for every opportunity.

Although we have created a custom price book 'Platinum (PL)' in system, but still it's always showing 'Standard price book' as default price book for every opportunity.

Please find below screenshot for your reference.

[image]

Is there any setting to make a pricebook default in the system ?
Please help on this. Thank you